# iPhone audio Filter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am considering an app which takes sound (eventually an audio track) and applies an audio filter to it.

So I can play sounds with AudioServicesPlaySystemSound via AudioToolbox framework just fine.

What I need is a very simple example of how I might take a sound and apply (for instance) midrange boost etc. Actually the kind of alteration is irrelevant -- if I can get my head around how the alteration is done I can figure out the rest. I am just finding both docs and examples of altering audio in code to be very scarce.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: WHich part do you need help with - hooking into the iPhone audio APIs or doing the actual DSP on the audio data itself ?

Comment: Actually it could be both! First I'm going to digest the Core Audio docs and make an attempt to do some simple dsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, anything beyond basic recording and playing of PCM data requires digging into the more murky depths of Core Audio.  I would probably start by looking at the [Core Audio Overview](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html) documentation from Apple.  They provide an entire mechanism with Audio Units for writing a signal processor or "effect units" that sit in the audio processing graph.

Comment: I just spent a few minutes in the Core Audio docs and I can see that my path def leads there. Thanks for the pointer!